# Facing issues to provide download link to shared files in django application

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am developing file sharing app using Django.
I have 3 models to store 
1: User information 
2: Information about there uploaded files
3: Information about file shared with them by another user

model number 2 and 3 are,

```
class user_files(models.Model):
    Filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Browse = models.FileField(upload_to='img/')
    user_uploaded = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/img/%s' % self.Browse.name

user_list = (User.objects.all())

class share_files(models.Model):
    select_file = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    from_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    select_user = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
```

I have written below function in view for sharing of file,

```
def user_share(request):
    user_data=User.objects.all()
    file_data = user_files.objects.filter(user_uploaded=request.user)
    select_user=request.POST.get('dropdown1')
    select_file=request.POST.get('dropdown2')

    if request.method=="POST":
        user_form = Share_file(request.POST)
        data=share_files(select_user=select_user,select_file=select_file)
        data.save()
        return redirect('share')

    else:
        user_form=Share_file()
        return render(request, 'accounts/share.html',{'user_form':user_form, 'user_data':user_data, 'file_data':file_data})
```

and the form for it is,

```
class Share_file(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = share_files
        fields = ('select_file', 'select_user')
```

I am displaying shared files in template , from model share_files but i also want to provide download option for that file. How can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can somebody please help me out?
I am still stuck at this point.

Comment: Firstly I think you have to work on your naming conventions so one can tell when you define a class and a function
Classes are known to be title case while functions are camel case.
**ThisIsAnExampleOfClass** and **thisIsAnExampleOfFunction**